Derivative of a convolution is the convolution with the left-derivative
In his book, Brownian motion, martingales and stochastic calculus, Le Gall used the following observation for Proposition 9.1, page 236:
"Let $f$ be a convex function (not necessaryly $C^1$) and $h$ be a nonegative function on $\mathbb R$ such that $h =0$ outside $[0,1]$ and that  $\int_{[0,1]} h(x)dx = 1$. For every $n\geq 1$, $h_n(x) := nh(nx)$ and define $\varphi_n: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ by
$$ \varphi_n (x) = h_n * f(x) = \int_\mathbb R h_n(y)f(x-y)dy. $$
Then it is elementary to verify $\varphi_n$ is $C^2$, $\varphi'_n = h_n * f'_-$, $\varphi_n(x) \rightarrow f(x) $, $\varphi'_n(x) \rightarrow f'_-(x)$."
Although he consider this to be elementary, I still don't see why the left derivative appears here. I believe he forgot to mention that $h$ should be smooth as well.
In my attempt I consider the limit
$$ \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0+} \frac{\varphi_n(x+\epsilon) - \varphi(x)}{\epsilon}  = \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0+} \int_\mathbb R h_n(y) \frac{f(x+\epsilon -y) - f(x-y)}{\epsilon}dy,$$
but clearly as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0+$
$$ \frac{f(x+\epsilon -y) - f(x-y)}{\epsilon}  \rightarrow f'_+(x-y),$$
the right derivative at $x-y$...
I dont see why $\varphi_n$ is $C^2$ and why the left limit appears there....

The function $h$ should be smooth, this is the same approach in the book by Revuz and Yor, page 221. Note that $f$ is almost everywhere differentiable and hence the left and right derivative agree almost everywhere. Thus,
$$ \frac{f(x \pm \epsilon-y) -f (x-y)}{\pm \epsilon} \overset{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}{\longrightarrow} f'_-(x-y) =f'_+(x-y), \quad y-a.e.$$
Now, $\varphi_n$ is twice differentiable because we can differentiate $h_n$ twice inside the integral instead of differentiating $f$. By bounded convergence,
$$ \varphi'_n = h_n *f'_- =h_n*f'_+. $$
For the last conclusion, $f'_-$ is left continuous, see e.g. this answer, so
$$\varphi'_n(x) -f'_-(x) = \int_{[0,1]}h(x)\left( f'_- \left(x- \frac{y}{n} \right) - f_-'(x)\right)dy \rightarrow 0 $$
as $n \rightarrow +\infty$.

Didn't realize the fact $f'- = f'+$ a.s., thanks!

I agree that some condition appears to be missing. For example if we take $f(x)=|x|$ and $h(x)=1_{[0,1]}(x)$, then for $n=1$ we get
$$\phi_1(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{2}-x & x<0
\\ x^2-x+\frac{1}{2} & 0\leq x\leq 1
\\ x-\frac{1}{2} & x>1
\end{cases}$$
which is $\mathcal{C}^1$ but not $\mathcal{C}^2$.

Nice example, I have one quite similar to yours :)
